# Matlab System generator: error with black box

Tags: matlab, vhdl, simulink, xilinx-ise, system-generator

I using Xilinx system generator blocks in Matlab.

I simply using only a black box with a gateway in and gateway out.

The code for the black box is very simple and work correctly with ISE design suite

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity test44_vhdl is
    Port ( row : in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
           slice : out  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
end test44_vhdl;

architecture Behavioral of test44_vhdl is

type oneD is array (1 to 3) of integer range 0 to 15;
constant table: oneD := (3, 9, 13);

begin

    slice <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(table(to_integer(unsigned(row))), slice'length));

end Behavioral;
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work with the matlab system generator.

I got the following error message

```
Exception: ISE Simulator Simulation failed during initialization.
```

can any one help me what is the wrong with this code and what change should I do so the model work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I checked the problem several times, I found the the error, is that, there is no value assigned to the array table when the input is "00"

So, the only changed that should I do, is to add a value to array at 0

```
type oneD is array (0 to 3) of integer range 0 to 15;
constant table: oneD := (3, 9, 13, 6);
```

now the model work correctly.